# P4Python - p4.run_changes returning empty list

Tags: perforce, p4python

The following code printing empty list "[]".I am expecting list of all change list between the date range specified. What do I need to fix to get the change list?

```
from P4 import P4,P4Exception

p4 = P4()
p4.port = "perforce:1666"
p4.user = "kvenkatraman"
p4.client = "kvenkatraman_tp"
p4.cwd = "C:\sv"


try:

    p4.connect()
    #info = p4.run("info")
    info = p4.run("changes","-s","submitted","\"//depot/psp/dev/...%402013/06/01,%40now\"")
    print info
    p4.disconnect()

except P4Exception:

    for e in p4.errors:
        print e
```

Regards
Kumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `"\"//depot/psp/dev/...%402013/06/01,%40now\""` to `"//depot/psp/dev/...@2013/06/01,@now"`

Comment: Your suggestion worked, Mike. thanks. Realized , I made a silly mistake.